# Sorting formulas that contain numbers and null values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, sorting

(There might be an answer to this question somewhere, but I can't find it. Sometimes you don't know how to ask a question in a search field. Sorry if I missed it.)

I have a sheet that I update with new data every day and five or six columns that each have formulas to manipulate the data which is then used for a work flow for my employees. Since I'm always adding new data I have 5000 rows of formula and the data I enter is usually less (say 3000). I have a formula that returns a numerical value 1-10 in order to rank the rows in importance, and if the row is blank it enters a value of "" instead.

This is clean and empty rows look great, but it then messes with my sorting feature (a field with "" as a value is "larger" than 10. Other things I've chosen as a return value for a blank row (-,0) all still sort to the top when I chose either ascending or descending.

For example:

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J2,Table!J:L,3,0),"")

Is there a value I can put in the field in place of "", or a format for a column, that can get all of my blank rows to stay to the bottom when I sort largest to smallest or vice versa?

Comment: Did you try defining a _custom sort sequence_?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a non-breaking space, which can be represented in an Excel formula as `CHAR(160)`.

So, your formula would look like this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J2,Table!J:L,3,0),CHAR(160))
```

Comment: That still only went to the bottom when I sorted smallest to largest (or rather A to Z), even though there is a number for each row not blank.

Comment: I had not noticed your "when I sort largest to smallest or vice versa" edit when I posted my answer. I can't see how there would be any value that will sort the way you want. No matter which value you use, the "blank" rows will still be on top when you sort one way, and on the bottom when you sort the opposite way.

Comment: I suppose I'll make them zero's then, since I'd much rather have them at the bottom with largest to smallest. Thanks.